# How to change dynamically input value attribute based on select option selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to update dynamically the input value attribute with data-price value based on option selection using jQuery.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".select").change(function () {
        newPrice = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
        console.log(newPrice);
       $(this).next('input').focus().val(newPrice);    
    });
</script>
<select class="select">
    <option value="1" data-price="2.99">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="3.99">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="4.99">3</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="5.99">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="">
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your `data-price="2.99"` is same for all.

Comment: Changed Now. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get/set the *attribute*.

**Please Note:** You also have to place the code after the HTML or warp the code with `$(document).ready(function(){....})`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select").change(function () {
      newPrice = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
      $(this).next('input').focus().attr('value', newPrice);    
      console.log('Element:', $(this).next('input')[0]);
    });
  });
</script>

<select class="select">
    <option value="1" data-price="2.99">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="3.99">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="4.99">3</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="5.99">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Many Thanks, Mamun:) selected data value showing in input but not in the value attribute. Ex: if the selected first option than input value="2.99". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

put your script at the bottom so it will apply the property change()

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="select">
    <option value="1" data-price="2.99">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="3.99">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="4.99">3</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="5.99">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".select").change(function () {
        newPrice = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
        console.log(newPrice);
       $(this).next('input').focus().val(newPrice);    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Many Thanks, EdBangs:) selected data value showing in input but not in the value attribute. Ex: if the selected first option than input value="2.99". Thanks

Comment: Add attr() for <input>

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="selectItem">
        <option value="1" data-price="2.99">1</option>
        <option value="2" data-price="2.99">2</option>
        <option value="3" data-price="2.99">3</option>
        <option value="4" data-price="2.99">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>

       $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#selectItem").on('change',function(){
      var newPrice=$(this).find('option').data('price');
      console.log(newPrice)
        $("input").val(newPrice)

    })    
      })
    </script>
```

Since you  don't have IDs So you can use like this with you code.

Answer (score 0):

When your code is executed, there is no `.select` element (the DOM is not ready).

Wrap you code inside

```
$(function(){...})
```

or use

```
$(document).on('change', '.select', function(){.....})
```

to set the listener.

Here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".select").change(function() {
      newPrice = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
      console.log(newPrice);
      $(this).next('input').focus().val(newPrice);
    });
  });
</script>
<select class="select">
  <option value="1" data-price="2.99">1</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="2.99">2</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="2.99">3</option>
  <option value="4" data-price="2.99">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Many Thanks, Titus:) selected data value showing in input but not in the value attribute. Ex: if the selected first option than input value="2.99". Thanks